# Deleting non-empty directory without w permission while having w permission in parent directory

Tags: permissions, rm

Here's the situation:

```
dir1/dir2/file.txt
```

permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx   4 me group 4.0K Jan 11 17:53 dir1
drwxr-xr-x 4 other_guy group 4.0K Jan 11 17:48 dir2
-rw-r--r-- 1 other_guy group 158 Jan 11 17:48 file.txt
```

Trying to remove dir2:

```
dir1> rm -rf dir2
rm: cannot remove 'dir2/file.txt': Permission denied
```

Is there any way to remove dir2 without root access?

Some context: I set up dir1 just to have a colleague share some files with me. He put dir2 and I processed everything, now I want to get rid of dir2. Is the only way to get rid of it to contact my colleague or the server admin?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407917/are-another-users-non-empty-subdirectories-safe-from-deletion-in-my-directory. Note that in that question, the user does not even have read permission on the non-empty subdir, thus cannot even see what's preventing them from removing the directory.

Comment: "Is there any way to remove dir2 without root access?" You can with `other_guy` access.

Comment: note that if this isn't done with malicious intent from `other_guy`, setting correct ACLs *before* `other_guy` creates a directory will grant joint inherited write access to anything created after in your directory, including subdirs.  (I'd say: `setfacl -m d:u:me:rwX -m d:u:other_guy:rwX dir1` ). Of course `other_guy` can revoke this on owned files.

Comment: So the only ways are with `other_guy` and `root` access? If both are unavailable and dir2 takes up all of my user's allocated disk data, the machine would be unusable for me?